# How to structure the data in firebase for large database to be very FAST

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

all my name is George and today I face a very big problem with firebase.
Can someone tell how to structure the database in firebase for large apps,

I have a database that is from MongoDB and is 50mb of data, How I structure the Firebase database to be fast for the user.

### My database schema is like this.

```
"firebase_database" : {

  // 20000 users

  "users" : {
    "user1" : {
      "name" : "some name"
    },
    "user2" : {
      "name" : "some name"
    },
    "user3" : {
      "name" : "some name"
    }
  },


  // 500 categories

  "kategories" : {
        "category1" : {
          "name" : "some name"
        },
        "category2" : {
          "name" : "some name"
        },
        "category3" : {
          "name" : "some name"
        }
      },


  // 100.000 products

  "products" : {
    "product1" : {
      "name" : "some name",
      "product_category" : "category1"
    },
    "product2" : {
      "name" : "some name",
      "product_category" : "category2"
    },
    "product3" : {
      "name" : "some name",
      "product_category" : "category1"
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This is all dependent on the functionality you are handling.

Comment: Using the word 'fast' is ambiguous at best, and is dependent on you, the internet connection and a number of other variables. There's nothing wrong with your structure and honestly, 50Mb of data is not a lot. Is there a speed issued you are currently encountering? If so, post your code - otherwise there's no way to answer the question.

Comment: no, i found that I need to add the index on firebase rules thanx  @Jay for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Data Denormalization.  Simply, duplicate the data to simplify and reduce querying.  Check out this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA&t=7s) from the Database Team.

Data duplication can be done on the server side using Cloud Functions. Check out this video on [Cloud Function Triggers for Database writes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0&t=2s).

Basically, when you write to the database, your cloud function will trigger and duplicate the data for you into different parts of the database.  This will reduce the workload on your client.

The data is duplicated in such a manner as to reduce or simplify the queries you are making for your database.  It helps flatten large structures and helps you download only the snapshot data that you need.

Comment: Thnx James yes that is what I want.

Comment: @George I don't think this is going to provide a solution. The structure posted in your question is about as denormalized as it's going to get, and duplicating data probably won't help. As it is, a list of 100k items isn't that much data so querying for an item or accessing it directly (with your structure) should be pretty instantaneous. The bottom line this isn't really an answer to *your* question - it's got good data points for sure but not a specific answer.